# Java Stream Executing Batch Before Loop Finish

Tags: java, java-stream

In the code below I am trying to insert batch data but executeBatch works before stream ends. And it works contionusly. How can I make executeBatch  to work after stream ends?

```
try (Connection dbConn = hConn.getHikariMap().get("" + connectionId).getConnection();) {
        Statement statement = dbConn.createStatement();
        if (fileData.get(0).length == 1) {

            fileData.stream().forEach(row -> {
                columnValTemp.append("','" + row[fileColumnOrder.get(0)] + "','" + row[fileColumnOrder.get(0)]);
                valuesTemp.append(columnValTemp);
                columnValTemp.setLength(0);
                values.append(valuesTemp);

                String query = "INSERT INTO " + schema + "." + tableName + " (" + columns + ") VALUES " + " ('" + values+ "')";
                try {
                    statement.addBatch(query);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                values.delete(values.length() - valuesTemp.length(), values.length());
                valuesTemp.setLength(0);
            });
            
            statement.executeBatch();
}
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error(e, e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: How do you know it executes before the stream ends?

Comment: It inserts query each seconds. And also I debugged it. I am expecting stream to finish then to insert all bacth queries at once.

Comment: Well if you think that it is cause of `stream()` but i don't think so you can use just `forEach` for collection - you don't need `stream()` here.

Comment: I also think it shouldn't  but it works with for loop but not with stream and forEach. Even if I print something right after stream it works before stream process ends.